# Towing a trailer - Turning at intersections - Begin your turn when the front of your vehicle is even with the left side of your intended lane

Tags: trailer

Does "even with" mean "parallel with the left side of the intended line you want to turn into" in the following statement? Or maybe I have interpreted it incorrectly? Thank you!

"[Begin your turn when the front of your vehicle is even with the left side of your intended lane.](https://www.alberta.ca/towing-a-trailer.aspx)"

Comment: Did you have a look at the diagrams in the link you referenced?  Those seem pretty clear to me.

Comment: Yes, I did. The problem is "even" has different meanings and I was not sure which one particular meaning applies in this case. I apologize for that.

Comment: Well, I don't believe you can learn to drive a vehicle towing a trailer by reading a brochure.  It takes a bit of practice.

Comment: Thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the linked diagram, it would appear that the vehicle operator should remain traveling straight through the intersection, until the imaginary line of the destination lane is crossed.  The instructions and diagram also support the suggestion that the vehicle should be operated as far to the right as practicable, both in the entry lane and the destination lane and returned to the center of the travel lane once the complete vehicle is out of the intersection.

[image: turning left image]
Image from linked site.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your detailed explanations!